# Deploy react app with nodejs, mysql and Express in hostinger

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I bought a hosting and a domain in hostinger, then I started to develop an application with react, nodejs, Mysql and Express and at the time of doing the deploy I realized that hostinger does not support node js unless I buy a vps which at this time I can not afford

My mistake was not to look at the details of hostinger, I bought it without having noticed.

The application is simple, it consists of a blog where there is a login, add, delete and update posts. Is there a way to make it compatible with node js or some solution for this?

A solution that can allow me to host my site on hostinger

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. the easy way is to create an api that can access your sql database and host it so that you can access the api from your react app. I have used python and flask to develop an api and hosted in on pythonanywhere. Just be careful as pauses the api every 3 months and if suppose you the api is paused, your username and password will not be authenticated and you might not able to view your react app unless you enable the api manually by logging into your account in pythonanywhere website. If there are any better solution please let me know.

**you can use this link to access the documentation on how to deploy your python flask api on python anywhere.**

https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/

**Also you can find documentation on how to create a flask api below.**
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-build-a-rest-api-using-flask/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).